# How to find the sequence function $f(n,x)$ of the three given functions?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, function-construction, sequence, generalized-function

I have the three functions $f(2,x)$, $f(3,x)$ and $f(4,x)$ where $x>0$

```
f2[x_]:= 16 x^2 - (1 - 4 x^2)^2 Cos[6 x] + (1 + 4 x^2)^2 Cos[12 x];


f3[x_]:=3 Sqrt[3] x (1 - 4 x^2)^2 - 3 Sqrt[3] x (1 + 24 x^2 + 16 x^4) Cos[6 x] - 
 24 (x^2 + 4 x^4) Sin[6 x] +  3/2 (1 - 4 x^2)^2 (1 + 4 x^2) Sin[12 x] - (1 + 4 x^2)^3 Sin[18 x];


f4[x_]:=1/4 + 28 x^2 + 8 x^4 (67 + 8 x^2 (7 + x^2)) - (1 - 4 x^2)^2 (1 + 24 x^2 + 16 x^4) Cos[6 x] - 1/4 (1 - 4 x^2)^4 Cos[12 x] + 2 (1 - 16 x^4)^2 Cos[18 x] - (1 + 4 x^2)^4 Cos[24 x] - 16 x (1 - 4 x^2)^2 (1 + 4 x^2) Sin[6 x] + 8 x (1 + 28 x^2 + 112 x^4 + 64 x^6) Sin[12 x];
```

**Question**
I am curious if there is a generating (sequence) function $f(n,x)$ which for $n=2,3,4$ gives respectively the above functions $f(2,x)$, $f(3,x)$ and $f(4,x)$. Is there a way to check (either numerically or analytically) whether there exists such a function?

Comment: [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) or [`FindLinearRecurrence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindLinearRecurrence.html)?

Comment: The first one I think. I want to find a function $f(n,x)$ which for $n=2,3,4$ gives the above functions. I am not familiar with your second option if it does the same job or not. @MarcoB